# Smooth scroll throws unexpected undefined property error

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, gsap

I've been trying to implement some kind of smooth scroll. I followed [this codepen](https://codepen.io/osublake/pen/QqPqbN) to create such scroll: https://codepen.io/osublake/pen/QqPqbN

I tried to translate into TypeScript/Angular, but it somehow still throws the following error - **not when `updateScroller()` is being called inside of `ngAfterViewInit`, but when I try to scroll for the first time** - pointing at `const resized = this.scroller.resizeRequest > 0`:

```
core.js:9110 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'scroller' of undefined
    at updateScroller (app.component.ts:50)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:391)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:34182)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:390)
    at Zone.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:168)
    at invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:465)
    at ZoneTask.invoke (zone-evergreen.js:454)
    at timer (zone-evergreen.js:2650)
```

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  scroller = {
    target: document.querySelector('.scrollable-container'),
    ease: 0.05,
    endY: 0,
    y: 0,
    resizeRequest: 1,
    scrollRequest: 0,
  };

  requestId = null;

  constructor(@Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
      console.log('Hi, this is NØREBRO!');
    }
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.scroller.target = document.querySelector('.scrollable-container');

      TweenLite.set(this.scroller.target, {
        rotation: 0.01,
        force3D: true
      });

      this.updateScroller();
    });
    window.focus();
  }

  updateScroller() {
    const html = document.documentElement;
    const body = document.body;

    const resized = this.scroller.resizeRequest > 0;

    if (resized) {
      const height = this.scroller.target.clientHeight;
      body.style.height = height + 'px';
      this.scroller.resizeRequest = 0;
    }

    const scrollY = window.pageYOffset || html.scrollTop || body.scrollTop || 0;

    this.scroller.endY = scrollY;
    this.scroller.y += (scrollY - this.scroller.y) * this.scroller.ease;

    if (Math.abs(scrollY - this.scroller.y) < 0.05 || resized) {
      this.scroller.y = scrollY;
      this.scroller.scrollRequest = 0;
    }

    TweenLite.set(this.scroller.target, {
      y: -this.scroller.y
    });

    this.requestId = this.scroller.scrollRequest > 0 ? requestAnimationFrame(this.updateScroller) : null;
  }

  @HostListener('window:scroll', [])
  scroll() {
    this.scroller.scrollRequest++;
    console.log(this.requestId);
    if (!this.requestId) {
      console.log('uff');
      this.requestId = requestAnimationFrame(this.updateScroller);
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `this` is `undefined` by repeated method calls. Without being able to debug your application, I assume that you need to add `this` as a scope to your `this.updateScroller` method.

The scope (`this`) of a function is always determined by the execution context and with `requestAnimationFrame` the function is called outside the context of your class instance (component). There are several interesting articles about function scopes, e.g. see [this](https://scotch.io/tutorials/understanding-scope-in-javascript).

There should be two ways to solve your problem:

**a)** Replace all `requestAnimationFrame(this.updateScroller)` calls with

```
requestAnimationFrame(this.updateScroller.bind(this))
```

**b)** Replace all `requestAnimationFrame(this.updateScroller)` calls with

```
requestAnimationFrame(() => {
  this.updateScroller()
})
```